# Explanation of an unknown symbolism regarding the set of real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vectors, real-numbers

I've find this symbol

$-\mathbb{R}_+^n$

of course we are talking of the set of nonnegative real numbers but what that minus sign means? For example I have

$X_i ∩ ( -\mathbb{R}_+^n)=${0}

what is the meaning of this intersection?

The context is theory of production, this expression is called "no free lunch" i.e. having production possibility set, $X_i⊂\mathbb{R}^n$, production is not free; there is no output
without input consumption.

Comment: If $X$ is a subset of an abelian group written additively $-X$ is standard notation for $\{-x \mid x \in X\}$. I can give no guarantee that this is the correct reading without knowing the context.

Comment: I have added further informations.

Comment: Does my suggestion make sense in that context?

Comment: If the components of $X_i$ are the consumptions of different inputs, then this interpretation makes sense: if all consumptions are nonpositive (no input is being consumed) then all consumptions must be zero (nothing is being produced either). Note that $\mathbb R_+$ must be the set of *nonnegative* reals, not positive reals, otherwise the intersection could not contain zero.

Comment: True, I've made the correction. So I have to consider $ -\mathbb{R}_+^n$ like $ \mathbb{R}_-^n$?

Comment: @Kolmogorovwannabe Also, in case you weren't aware, you can use \mathbb{R} for the Reals. $\mathbb{R}$